# Dynamic array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dynamic

I've got a problem with this:

```
if($.cookie('products') == undefined) {
    $.cookie("products", [$(this).data('name')]);
}
else $.cookie("products", [$.cookie('products')+$(this).data('name')]);
```

My goal is to add names of products to the cookie, cause I need to use them in PHP after sending them through a form.

I'm using array, because then in code I need to delete last object:

```
$.cookie("products", $.cookie('products').pop());
```

Or maybe you have another solution to transport variables from jQuery in one file to PHP's variables in another?

Comment: what the problem with the code you're using ?

Comment: The last element is not deleting, so I guess that there's problem with correct creating array - probably syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I managed with main problem using this:

```
var products = [$.cookie('products')];
products.push($(this).data('name'));
$.cookie("products", products);
```

But there's still a problem with pop() method:

```
products.pop();
$.cookie("products", products);
```

Instead of deleting only a last element it removes the whole array.